# Mostrar palabras al azar con Node.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Quiero que se den palabras al azar y no sale nada.

```js
const palabras = ["hola", "zorro", "kilogramo","viento", "diente", "cabello", "fuego", "lluvia"];

var mipalabra = Math.round(Math.random() * palabra.length);

module.exports= miPalabra;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deberías exportar una función

```
const frases = ["hola", "zorro", "kilogramo","viento", "diente", "cabello", "fuego", "lluvia"];

module.exports.generaFrase = function() {
    const fraseIndex = Math.round(Math.random() * frases.length);
    return frases[fraseIndex];
};
```

Luego donde la vayas a usar

```
const {generaFrase} = require('./ruta-a-mi-modulo-de-frases');

const fraseAlAzar = generaFrase(); // Será una de "hola", "cabello", etc
```

Comment: no me sale nada

Comment: @Angel Especifica mejor que es nada. Como estas importando el módulo o cómo lo llamas?

Answer (score 3):

te sugiero realizarlo de la siguiente forma:

```js
const frases = ["Buenos Dias", "Buenas Tardes", "Buenas Noches","ADIOS"];
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*frases.length);
alert(frases[randomNumber])
```

espero te sirva, ¡suerte!

Comment: Si se usa tu código en NodeJS, el mismo producirá el siguiente error: `ReferenceError: alert is not defined`. Aunque NodeJS es Javascript, el mismo se ejecuta en el lado servidor, en el cual no existe el [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM), por lo tanto no existe el objeto `window` y tampoco el método `alert`. Revisa tu respuesta. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
const palabras = ["hola", "zorro", "kilogramo","viento", "diente", "cabello", "fuego", "lluvia"];

var mipalabra = Math.round(Math.random() * palabra.length);
// solo exporta palabras en la posicion miPalabra
module.exports= palabras[miPalabra];
```

Comment: Tu código arrojaría un error en `palabra.length` ya que palabra no está definido....es `palabras.length`, saludos

Comment: @BenderPaisa muchas gracias no me percate solo copie y pege!